# Grammatical terms used in the definitions of the Oxford English Dictionary

Tags: grammar, dictionaries, lexicography

For example, the entry for the noun ["*counsel*"](https://www.oed.com/oed2/00051624) reads:

> *(Usually a **collective plural**, but sometimes treated as a **numeral plural**; formerly, in ‘to desire the benefit of counsel’, treated as a
>   **collective sing.:** cf. quot. 1681.)*

I'd like to know where I can find the definitions/explanations of all the *grammatical terms* used throughout the OED, such as *collective plural, numeral plural, collective singular.*

Edit: The terms don't appear either in [the Glossary of grammatical terms](https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/glossary-grammatical-terms/)

Comment: @Andrew I'm pretty sure that requests for explanations of dictionary terminology (for individual dictionaries) (and the underlying assumptions about grammar) are off-topic. Are they (as opposed to requests for resources) even on-topic on ELU.Meta?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since "grammar" is on-topic, it seems reasonable to me that explanations of grammatical terms can be on-topic too. This might even have historical significance, if terms have changed over the years. Yes, this refers specifically to OED, but the term is/was probably more widely used. You or others may disagree: feel free to ask on Meta about whether specific terms of grammar should be on-topic.

Comment: _The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar_ defines all five bold words in your question. I assume that it also defines the other grammatical terms used in definitions in the OED.

Comment: @Andrew Leach There's a vast difference between 'Can anyone explain the terms 'collective plural', 'numeral plural' and 'collective singular'; they are found for example here in OED [+ linked quote]' **and** 'I'd like to know where I can find the definitions/explanations of all the grammatical terms used throughout the OED'. // On seeing Shoe's response above, a 'lack of research' CV here is perhaps best.

Comment: [Tanya Reinhart, in _Non-definiteness and Plurality_](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=zY86AAAAQBAJ&pg=PA295&lpg=PA295&dq=%22numeral+plural%22&source=bl&ots=IijneNMk1F&sig=ACfU3U0Z7ADNmjSUjrbFVL1-lT_06u5c7A&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22numeral%20plural%22&f=false), uses the string 'number plural' to label [integer + count-usage of noun in plural form], harder to define rigorously than to illustrate, eg three coffees, 26 million virions, or 76 trombones. I think OED's usage of the term must be different. I think that 'notional agreement' is a good term to start with hereabouts.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here's a copy of Shoe's reference on which you both support your false statements. Tell us please the pages where those are defined https://filebin.net/tkslsfrzuj78be5x

Comment: I think I've made 9 statements above. Which do you think is/are false? // Shoe has given a resource you could try. I've given a usage of the string (_term_?) 'number plural', attributed and linked. You, however, have provided no signs of reasonable research. EDIT Ah, now you have, while I was typing. If it's an inadequate glossary, you should contact the editors. // The sense of 'number plural' Reinhart uses probably being different from that OED use, there is obviously ill-definition hereabouts. Only the OED board can explain the specifying definitions they have chosen and their reasons.